# Which WP-CLI commands can be safely run with --allow-root flag?

Tags: security, wp-cli

Over the past several years, WP-CLI has become pretty popular, but there's still a lot of warnings about the `--allow-root` flag for security reasons, and instead developers are urged to use non-root users.

But, there's also a lot of cases, like setting up crontab jobs to repeat certain tasks, where `--allow-root` ensures that the tasks are run properly without interaction.

Which commands might be "safely" run using this flag, esp. in cron jobs?

Answer (score 1):

**None are safe when ran as root.** Even WP CLI help screens aren't safe.

The reason the `--allow-root` flag is considered dangerous is not because of what the CLI commands themselves do, but because your entire sites code is loaded when WP CLI runs, but now as root. This would mean any hidden malware would now have root on your server, and any code that makes a mistake has no guard rails to prevent it destroying the entire machine. For this reason all commands are just as dangerous.

Fundamentally, it should never be necessary to run WP CLI as a root user, and if you're logged in as `root` you can still run WP CLI as another non-root user to avoid the security issues via `sudo`, e.g. this is one way to do it:

```sh
function noroot() {
  sudo -EH -u "webuser" "$@";
}

noroot wp post list # <- runs as webuser not root
```

Other methods exist, but using a shell session with a non-root user is still preferable.